# Partition to calculate a percentage across a "collapsed" numeric variable

Tags: sql, vertica

I've got a table of person data with age in years. I'd like to calculate the percentage of people in my table across three or more collapsed categories of ages, such as 18 - 29, 30 - 39, 40 - 49, etc, using SQL.

Basically, I want my table to look like this:

```
Count | AgeCat | percent
400 | 50 and older | .40
300 | 35 to 49 | .30
300 | Under 35 | .30
```

Here is my query:

```
select count(*), 
case when age >= 50 then '50 and older' when age < 50 and age >= 35 then '35 to 49' else 'Under 35' end as AgeCat,
count(*)/sum(count(*)) over (partition by '') as percent 
from mydata group by 2;
```

The window function above only works when I limit my age collapse to a two category collapse (over / under 50).

Comment: Please post the output of your query. Try adding `sum(count(*)) over (partition by '')` as a column to see what value you are getting there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select count(*), 
       (case when age >= 50 then '50 and older'
             when age < 50 and age >= 35 then '35 to 49' 
             else 'Under 35'
        end) as AgeCat,
       count(*)/sum(count(*)) over (partition by '') as percent 
from mydata
group by 2;
```

This should work.  However, I would write it as:

```
select count(*), 
       (case when age >= 50 then '50 and older'
             when age >= 35 then '35 to 49' 
             else 'Under 35'
        end) as AgeCat,
       ( count(*) / sum(count(*)) over () ) as percent 
from mydata
group by AgeCat
order by min(age);
```